# Indirect way to insert javascript into an html page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I encountered the following script in a webpage source :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {"typekit":{"id":"cmr1bul"}};
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = 'https://s1.wp.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-fonts/js/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
    })();
</script>
```

From what I see, this script inserts the content of https://s1.wp.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-fonts/js/webfont.js
before the first script in the page. What is the difference between the above and putting

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s1.wp.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-fonts/js/webfont.js"> </script>
```

as the first script in the page ? What is gained by using the longer version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely equivalent to the following code if both script elements are added before any other one:

```
<script>WebFontConfig = {"typekit":{"id":"cmr1bul"}};</script>
<script src="https://s1.wp.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-fonts/js/webfont.js" async></script>
```

...or:

```
<script src="https://s1.wp.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-fonts/js/webfont.js" async></script>
<script>WebFontConfig = {"typekit":{"id":"cmr1bul"}};</script>
```

...because the script is asynchronously included...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's why I'm telling the OP that's just before adding them *before*. Am I mistaken? :D

Comment: Got it : the advantage of the longer version is that it may be put anywhere in the page, it will always result in the webfont.js being put first.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Yeah... BTW unless the script must be really added this way, I suggest you to use script elements..